# python script to download attachments in email having keywords in subject line

Tags: python, outlook, pop3

```
import getpass, poplib, email, parse
from poplib  import POP3
user = 'rnandipati@qwerty.com' 
M = poplib.POP3_SSL('outlook.office365.com', '995') 
M.user(user) 
M.pass_('R7!')
numMessages = len(M.list()[1])
print ("You have %d messages." % (numMessages))
print ("Message List:")

M.quit()
```

I have the above code that gives the number of messages in my email. I want to download attachments from the messages that have "hello" in the subject line.

What i have tried:

```
 for mList in range(numMessages):
        for msg in M.retr(mList+1)[1]:
            if msg.startswith('Subject'):
                print(msg)
                break
```

I have looked at a lot of examples online and really need help with this. I am also a newbie in such scripting.

Thank You.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE i have tried to find the subject of each email but it keeps saying that bytes expected in place of string. Please suggest a page that shows me how to look for strings in subject and then i can move forwards.

Comment: Please, post your code and stack trace.

Comment: Does that print anything out?

Comment: it prints the number of emails @jknupp

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE I have attached what i tried. that code just reads the subject lines which i haven't been able to achieve.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE the error generated is `TypeError: startswith first arg must be bytes or a tuple of bytes, not str`

Comment: @Rahul: try this: `msg.startswith(b'Subject')`. With a "b" prefix.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE That did it!! i just removed \t and it worked!

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE Just one more question. How do i store the value of each subject line in a variable?

Comment: @Rahul: create a list and append the subjects to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the documentation:

> POP3.retr(*which*)
>
> Retrieve whole message number *which*, and set its seen flag. Result is in form (response, ['line', ...], octets).

So `M.retr(mList+1)[1]` is a list of lines.

You are iterating a list of strings, which can be unicode ou bytes strings.

The documentation doesn't say much about which type of string you get, but, if you are using Python 3, I make the assumption that it is unicode string.

So: `msg.startswith("Subject:")` should work.

Comment: I didn't quite understand how would i incorporate `POP3.retr(which(mList+1)[1]:` in my code. Are you saying i should?

Comment: Sorry, but you removed your code sample... So the answer is out of context

Comment: I put it back @LaurentLAPORTE

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway.